# plotting multiple box plots for repeated measures for 238 subjects using ggplot2 in a single graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

i got 238 patients. each patient came on a monthly visit and had pre void urine volume estimation and post void urine volume estimation. now this was done 23 times for every patient over almost two years.i want to plot boxplots for pre and post void urine for entire population to see trend over time (for each visit) in a single graph. the prevoid volumes are usually 300+ while post void volumes are <50. Is there a way to do it in **ggplot2**? i could only make 2 separate graphs using boxplot (one showing multiple prevoids over time in single graph with medians connected via line and another showing similar thing with post void).....in fact i could not draw even one box plot with ggplot as somehow my data doesn't have x y axis

i tried plotrix and what not...nothing worked.

This kind of code worked somewhat with `boxplot()`

```
boxplot((mydata)[,c(13:35)], outline=FALSE, xlab= "Time in months", ylab="Prevoid urine",las=2)       ##plots box plots of columns 13-35 in one graph(23 boxplots)with outliers suppressed

p<-lines(1:23,(boxplot((mydata)[,c(13:35)],outline=FALSE, col="yellow", xlab= "Time in months", ylab="prevoid urine", las=2,ylim = c(0, 600)))$stats[3,], col="blue", lwd=3)        ##plots blue line connecting medians of 23 boxplots shaded yellow
```

Comment: Please post data with `dput`. Is `13:35` the 23 columns for *pre* or *post*? Is there a *year* indicator? And please describe what is wrong with `boxplot` code as *this kind of code worked somewhat* is not descriptive for us.

Answer (score 0):

Would the [facet options in ggplot](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html) be useful for your purposes?

Comment: It is best to explain the answer here in case the link changes or goes dead.

Answer (score 0):

Consider calling `sapply` to calculate `median` then pass that vector into `lines` to avoid calling `boxplot` again for second unneeded plot:

```
## plots box plots of columns 13-35 in one graph(23 boxplots)with outliers suppressed
boxplot(mydata[,c(13:35)], outline=FALSE, xlab= "Time in months", ylab="Prevoid urine",las=2)   

## plots blue line connecting medians of 23 boxplots shaded yellow
lines(1:23, sapply(mydata[,c(13:35)], median), col="blue", lwd=3)
```

To demonstrate with random data:

```
set.seed(8132019)
mydata <- data.frame(replicate(35, runif(500, 300, 500)))

boxplot(...)
lines(...)
```

[image: Plot Output]

Answer (score 0):

Your data is quite messy and we don't have a bunch of information about the order of the variables. For what you provided on an answer that you deleted, this is as much as I could do.

### The data

```
mydata <-data.frame(   serialnumber = 1:238,
                       urinarysummarypreop = c(68.75, 87.5, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 87.5, 68.75, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 87.5, 81.25, 87.5, 81.25, 87.5, 68.75, 87.5, 87.5, 81.25, 81.25, 68.75, 68.75, 81.25, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 68.75, 81.25, 87.5, 81.25, 68.75, 77.08333333, 81.25, 77.08333333, 68.75, 81.25, 81.25, 68.75, 81.25, 87.5, 81.25, 68.75, 81.25, 68.75, 68.75, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 68.75, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 81.25, 81.25, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 81.25, 77.08333333, 87.5, 77.08333333, 87.5, 87.5, 68.75, 87.5, 87.5, 81.25, 81.25, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 81.25, 87.5, 81.25, 81.25, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 87.5, 81.25, 87.5, 87.5, 77.08333333, 77.08333333, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 81.25, 81.25, 87.5, 77.08333333, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 81.25, 87.5, 81.25, 68.75, 81.25, 87.5, 87.5, 68.75, 87.5, 81.25, 87.5, 87.5, 81.25, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 81.25, 77.08333333, 81.25, 87.5, 77.08333333, 87.5, 81.25, 68.75, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 77.08333333, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 77.08333333, 87.5, 87.5, 77.08333333, 81.25, 77.08333333, 87.5, 77.08333333, 81.25, 87.5, 81.25, 87.5, 81.25, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 81.25, 81.25, 87.5, 77.08333333, 87.5, 81.25, 81.25, 77.08333333, 81.25, 87.5, 68.75, 81.25, 87.5, 68.75, 68.75, 87.5, 77.08333333, 87.5, 87.5, 81.25, 87.5, 77.08333333, 81.25, 87.5, 87.5, 77.08333333, 77.08333333, 81.25, 87.5, 87.5, 81.25, 87.5, 87.5, 81.25, 87.5, 81.25, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 81.25, 81.25, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 87.5, 77.08333333, 87.5, 87.5, 77.08333333, 87.5, 81.25, 87.5, 87.5, 77.08333333, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 87.5, 81.25, 81.25, 68.75, 87.5, 87.5, 81.25, 68.75, 87.5, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 87.5, 81.25),
                       urinarysummary6wks = c(26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 16.66666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 16.66666667, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 16.66666667, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 16.66666667, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 16.66666667, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 16.66666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 22.16666667, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333, 26.33333333),
                       urinarysummary3months = c(36.16666667, 57.66666667, 48.66666667, 32, 48.66666667, 26.33333333, 44.5, 36.16666667, 48.66666667, 46.58333333, 36.16666667, 57.66666667, 57.66666667, 48.66666667, 32, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 48.66666667, 46.58333333, 36.16666667, 48.66666667, 30.5, 32, 44.5, 36.16666667, 32, 57.66666667, 48.66666667, 36.16666667, 48.66666667, 36.16666667, 57.66666667, 57.66666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 48.66666667, 46.58333333, 22.16666667, 36.16666667, 57.66666667, 44.5, 30.5, 57.66666667, 48.66666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 48.66666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 32, 36.16666667, 32, 36.16666667, 32, 36.16666667, 48.66666667, 57.66666667, 36.16666667, 48.66666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 46.58333333, 26.33333333, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 57.66666667, 48.66666667, 36.16666667, 48.66666667, 36.16666667, 48.66666667, 57.66666667, 32, 36.16666667, 46.58333333, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 48.66666667, 48.66666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 46.58333333, 36.16666667, 57.66666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 32, 57.66666667, 48.66666667, 36.16666667, 26.33333333, 36.16666667, 48.66666667, 48.66666667, 57.66666667, 48.66666667, 57.66666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 46.58333333, 36.16666667, 48.66666667, 41.66666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 32, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 48.66666667, 44.5, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 46.58333333, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 26.33333333, 48.66666667, 36.16666667, 48.66666667, 36.16666667, 22.16666667, 32, 57.66666667, 32, 32, 48.66666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 48.66666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 48.66666667, 48.66666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 46.58333333, 46.58333333, 46.58333333, 36.16666667, 48.66666667, 36.16666667, 32, 36.16666667, 48.66666667, 30.5, 48.66666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 48.66666667, 46.58333333, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 46.58333333, 26.33333333, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 32, 57.66666667, 32, 30.5, 48.66666667, 32, 57.66666667, 36.16666667, 48.66666667, 36.16666667, 32, 46.58333333, 36.16666667, 46.58333333, 48.66666667, 36.16666667, 46.58333333, 36.16666667, 48.66666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 46.58333333, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 46.58333333, 57.66666667, 36.16666667, 46.58333333, 46.58333333, 48.66666667, 36.16666667, 48.66666667, 57.66666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 46.58333333, 48.66666667, 32, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 32, 16.66666667, 36.16666667, 48.66666667, 46.58333333, 36.16666667, 48.66666667, 41.66666667, 46.58333333, 36.16666667, 16.66666667, 36.16666667, 48.66666667, 32, 36.16666667, 32, 36.16666667, 57.66666667, 30.5, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 36.16666667, 57.66666667 ),
                       urinaryfunctionpreop = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L),
                       urinaryfunction6wks = c(16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 0, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 0, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 0, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 0, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 0, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 0, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5),
                       urinaryfunction3months = c(33.5, 66.75, 58.5, 33.5, 58.5, 16.5, 58.5, 33.5, 58.5, 33.5, 33.5, 66.75, 66.75, 58.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 58.5, 33.5, 33.5, 58.5, 16.5, 33.5, 58.5, 33.5, 33.5, 66.75, 58.5, 33.5, 58.5, 33.5, 66.75, 66.75, 33.5, 33.5, 58.5, 33.5, 16.5, 33.5, 66.75, 58.5, 16.5, 66.75, 58.5, 33.5, 33.5, 58.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 58.5, 66.75, 33.5, 58.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 16.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 66.75, 58.5, 33.5, 58.5, 33.5, 58.5, 66.75, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 58.5, 58.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 66.75, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 66.75, 58.5, 33.5, 16.5, 33.5, 58.5, 58.5, 66.75, 58.5, 66.75, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 58.5, 50, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 58.5, 58.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 16.5, 58.5, 33.5, 58.5, 33.5, 16.5, 33.5, 66.75, 33.5, 33.5, 58.5, 33.5, 33.5, 58.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 58.5, 58.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 58.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 58.5, 16.5, 58.5, 33.5, 33.5, 58.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 16.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 66.75, 33.5, 16.5, 58.5, 33.5, 66.75, 33.5, 58.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 58.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 58.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 66.75, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 58.5, 33.5, 58.5, 66.75, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 58.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 0, 33.5, 58.5, 33.5, 33.5, 58.5, 50, 33.5, 33.5, 0, 33.5, 58.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 66.75, 16.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 66.75),
                       urinarybotherpreop = c(53.125, 81.25, 71.875, 71.875, 71.875, 71.875, 81.25, 53.125, 71.875, 71.875, 71.875, 81.25, 71.875, 81.25, 71.875, 81.25, 53.125, 81.25, 81.25, 71.875, 71.875, 53.125, 53.125, 71.875, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 71.875, 71.875, 71.875, 53.125, 71.875, 81.25, 71.875, 53.125, 65.625, 71.875, 65.625, 53.125, 71.875, 71.875, 53.125, 71.875, 81.25, 71.875, 53.125, 71.875, 53.125, 53.125, 71.875, 71.875, 71.875, 71.875, 53.125, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 71.875, 71.875, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 71.875, 65.625, 81.25, 65.625, 81.25, 81.25, 53.125, 81.25, 81.25, 71.875, 71.875, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 71.875, 81.25, 71.875, 71.875, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 71.875, 71.875, 71.875, 81.25, 71.875, 81.25, 81.25, 65.625, 65.625, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 71.875, 71.875, 81.25, 65.625, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 71.875, 81.25, 71.875, 53.125, 71.875, 81.25, 81.25, 53.125, 81.25, 71.875, 81.25, 81.25, 71.875, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 71.875, 65.625, 71.875, 81.25, 65.625, 81.25, 71.875, 53.125, 71.875, 71.875, 71.875, 71.875, 65.625, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 65.625, 81.25, 81.25, 65.625, 71.875, 65.625, 81.25, 65.625, 71.875, 81.25, 71.875, 81.25, 71.875, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 71.875, 71.875, 81.25, 65.625, 81.25, 71.875, 71.875, 65.625, 71.875, 81.25, 53.125, 71.875, 81.25, 53.125, 53.125, 81.25, 65.625, 81.25, 81.25, 71.875, 81.25, 65.625, 71.875, 81.25, 81.25, 65.625, 65.625, 71.875, 81.25, 81.25, 71.875, 81.25, 81.25, 71.875, 81.25, 71.875, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 71.875, 71.875, 81.25, 81.25, 81.25, 71.875, 71.875, 71.875, 71.875, 81.25, 65.625, 81.25, 81.25, 65.625, 81.25, 71.875, 81.25, 81.25, 65.625, 71.875, 71.875, 71.875, 81.25, 71.875, 71.875, 53.125, 81.25, 81.25, 71.875, 53.125, 81.25, 71.875, 71.875, 71.875, 81.25, 71.875),
                       urinarybother6wks = c(31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 25, 31.25, 25, 31.25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 31.25, 25, 31.25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 25, 31.25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 31.25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 25, 31.25, 25, 31.25, 25, 25, 31.25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 31.25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25), urinarybother3months = c(37.5, 53.125, 43.75, 31.25, 43.75, 31.25, 37.5, 37.5, 43.75, 53.125, 37.5, 53.125, 53.125, 43.75, 31.25, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 43.75, 53.125, 37.5, 43.75, 37.5, 31.25, 37.5, 37.5, 31.25, 53.125, 43.75, 37.5, 43.75, 37.5, 53.125, 53.125, 37.5, 37.5, 43.75, 53.125, 25, 37.5, 53.125, 37.5, 37.5, 53.125, 43.75, 37.5, 37.5, 43.75, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 31.25, 37.5, 31.25, 37.5, 31.25, 37.5, 43.75, 53.125, 37.5, 43.75, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 53.125, 31.25, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 53.125, 43.75, 37.5, 43.75, 37.5, 43.75, 53.125, 31.25, 37.5, 53.125, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 43.75, 43.75, 37.5, 37.5, 53.125, 37.5, 53.125, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 31.25, 53.125, 43.75, 37.5, 31.25, 37.5, 43.75, 43.75, 53.125, 43.75, 53.125, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 53.125, 37.5, 43.75, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 31.25, 37.5, 37.5, 43.75, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 53.125, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 31.25, 43.75, 37.5, 43.75, 37.5, 25, 31.25, 53.125, 31.25, 31.25, 43.75, 37.5, 37.5, 43.75, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 43.75, 43.75, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 53.125, 53.125, 53.125, 37.5, 43.75, 37.5, 31.25, 37.5, 43.75, 37.5, 43.75, 37.5, 37.5, 43.75, 53.125, 37.5, 37.5, 53.125, 31.25, 37.5, 37.5, 31.25, 53.125, 31.25, 37.5, 43.75, 31.25, 53.125, 37.5, 43.75, 37.5, 31.25, 53.125, 37.5, 53.125, 43.75, 37.5, 53.125, 37.5, 43.75, 37.5, 37.5, 53.125, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 53.125, 53.125, 37.5, 53.125, 53.125, 43.75, 37.5, 43.75, 53.125, 37.5, 37.5, 53.125, 43.75, 31.25, 37.5, 37.5, 31.25, 25, 37.5, 43.75, 53.125, 37.5, 43.75, 37.5, 53.125, 37.5, 25, 37.5, 43.75, 31.25, 37.5, 31.25, 37.5, 53.125, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 53.125)
```

### Reshape

We need to reshape the data and clean the variable names.
The column names hide 2 to 3 different variables. This is not the way `ggplot2` likes things (that's probably why you are having trouble).

```
m_data <- reshape2::melt(mydata, id.vars=c("serialnumber")) %>%
  separate(variable, into = c("urinary", "timepoint"), "bother|summary|function", remove=FALSE) %>%
  mutate(variable = str_extract(variable, "bother|summary|function"))%>%
  dplyr::select(-urinary)
```

Take a peak of how the data looks now

```
 serialnumber variable timepoint value
1            1  summary     preop 68.75
2            2  summary     preop 87.50
3            3  summary     preop 81.25
4            4  summary     preop 81.25
5            5  summary     preop 81.25
6            6  summary     preop 81.25
```

### Create an ordered x axis

Now let's put the visits in order (not sure this is the way but I have no more info so...).

> **Warning:** By doing this, I'm mixing the "summary", "bother", and "function" values

```
m_data <- m_data %>%
  group_by(serialnumber) %>%
  mutate(visit_num = 1:length(serialnumber))
```

## Plot

Now you can do the plot

```
m_data  %>%
  ggplot(aes(factor(visit_num), value, group=serialnumber)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(factor(visit_num), value, group=visit_num))+
  geom_line(color="red", alpha=0.01)+
  theme_bw()+
  NULL
```

[image]

I'm surprised that the timepoint 4 has 0 variability...what's going on with your data ?

Additionally I only had 9 timepoints per patient, weren't we supposed to have 23 ?